# occurs segmentation fault while overloading operator >> for the Complex class

Tags: c++

If I want to use sentence like this in my c++ program,

```
while (cin >> c)
  {
    cout << c << endl;
  }
```

**c is a Complex class I define before.**

how can I overload the operator >> for my *Complex* class

I have tried two methods, but all fail due to **segmentation fault** when the program run the above sentence *cin>>c* for the second time,

```
and the first method is 

friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Complex& right)
{
    char a;
    char temp[50];
    int cnt = 0;
    double i = 0;
    double r = 0;
    while (in >> a)
    {
        if (a == ')')
        {
            temp[cnt] = a;
            break;
        }
        temp[cnt++] = a;
    }
    sscanf(temp, "(%lf,%lf)", &r, &i);
    right.real = r;
    right.imag = i;
}
```

the second method is

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Complex& right)
{
    double r = 0;
    double i = 0;
    in.ignore();
    in >> r;
    in.ignore();
    in >> i;
    in.ignore();
    right.real = r;
    right.imag = i;
}
```

my input is like this

**(1.5,2)(1,2.5)(1.5,2.5)(0,0)(1,2)**

Can anyone give some hints?

#### After I add nullptr at the end of temp,

I still encounter the same problem, the following are the erroe

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000000401285 in f () at main.cpp:75
>   75    while (cin >> c)
>   (gdb) s

Comment: you should null-terminate `temp` before calling `sscanf`. And check that `temp` does not get overflowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is that you are calling `sscanf` using a string that is not null terminated.

```
while (in >> a)
{
    if (a == ')')
    {
        temp[cnt] = a;
        break;
    }
    temp[cnt++] = a;
}

// Need to null terminate temp
temp[cnt+1] = '\0';
sscanf(temp, "(%lf,%lf)", &r, &i);
```

Comment: but after I modify as you instruct, I depressingly find I still encounter segmentation fault while the program run into the sentence "while(cin >> c)", is there any other problems exist ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is `operator>>` and not `operator >>` (note the missing space).

Secondly, why not just this:

```
friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Complex& right)
{
    in >> right.real;
    in >> right.imag;
}
```

Note: You'll also have to overload `operator<<` for `cout << c << endl` to work.

Comment: `operator >>` is the same as `operator>>`. That would not be a problem.

Comment: I still have a question, I input '(' before the real and imag number, why "in "can ignore these character '('  ',' ')' and still read the number